# Overlay Other GUI Elements Over GStreamer Video

Tags: python, video, pygtk, gstreamer

I have a project built in Python, PyGTK 2.24, and PyGST (GStreamer). I have my video working perfectly in a gtk.DrawingArea object.

However, I need to display other GUI elements OVER this video while it is playing. (Please don't ask why, just trust me.) Right now, they all appear to be behind. In the code, the video objects (and gtk.DrawingArea) are declared and put into the gtk.Fixed FIRST, following by everything else.

So, how do I do this? Do I need to change what object GStreamer is playing on? I know it is possible...I've seen GStreamer programs that have things like buttons and labels sitting on top of the video.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I render Text with transparent background over other widgets in GTK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296618/how-can-i-render-text-with-transparent-background-over-other-widgets-in-gtk)

Comment: Platform differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in GTK 3.2 and above using [`GtkOverlay`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkOverlay.html).

If you can't upgrade, then here is a summary of the old-fashioned way: connect to the `expose-event` signal of the `DrawingArea`, and paint the information on yourself using Cairo. When the information changes, trigger a redraw of the drawing area using `widget.queue_draw()`. Make sure your handler runs *after* the handler that draws the actual video onto the drawing area. This will work for labels and non-interactive GUI elements.

If you want an actual functioning GUI element to hover above your video, that's rather more complicated and I don't know how to do it. I don't think `Fixed` guarantees any z-order. I suspect that your buttons and whatnot are being overpainted by the video being drawn onto the drawing area, so maybe triggering a redraw of those in your `expose-event` handler will work.

Comment: That is not available in PyGTK, according to the documentation. I need something that matches my stated project specifications, please.

Comment: @JasonMc92: Ok, but you didn't specify that upgrading was impossible. Keep in mind that the programs in which you saw it was possible may use GTK 3 themselves.

Comment: @downvoter: not everybody who comes to this question from Google is going to have the same project specifications as Jason.

Comment: I originally downvoted because the answer was not useful at all (which is verbatum what a downvote means. Now that you extended it to something which matches my project specs (and additionally, perhaps other people's), I can upvote. Anyway, I don't think it is possible to "upgrade" anything here. The latest version of PyGTK is 2.24, and I must use PyGTK, since I need the Python bindings.

Comment: @JasonMc92, PyGTK has been superseded by PyGObject, which covers 3.0 and up. PyGObject is the new Python bindings.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have the time to rework my code. Would I need to? Furthermore, will it work with Python 2.7? I cannot upgrade to Python 3 for backward compatibilty reasons.

Comment: Well, you'd need to rework your code a little bit to use GTK 3.0 and up in whatever language - see http://developer.gnome.org/Gnome3PortingGuide/ - then there's http://live.gnome.org/PyGObject/IntrospectionPorting for porting to PyGObject, which seems mostly to be search and replace. I don't know for sure if PyGObject works with Python 2.7, but I think it does.

Comment: I know PyGObject is a prerequisite for PyGTK...I'll look into that. TY.

Answer (score 2):

Probably of no use to the OP, but I searched for a long time looking for a way to place widgets over the top of a gtk.gdk.Drawable element (which could be a statically drawn image, animation or video) before I finally figured out how to do this in pygtk2.

Here's a link to what I came up with: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~damien-moore/picty/trunk/view/642/modules/picty/overlay_widgets.py

This includes 3 custom classes:

ProportionalLayout: an implementation of a custom gtk.Container that lets the user position child widgets using proportions.

DrawableOverlay: an EventBox that emits a 'draw' event for the user to connect to and do drawing on, and displays a ProportionalLayout on top.

DrawableOverlayHover: a DrawableOverlayHover that only shows the widgets if the pointer gets "close" to them.

The sample **main** program illustrates how to use them. The code should be reasonably straightforward to adapt to a video application.

Comment: While I've switched languages altogether, I'm sure this'll be a useful solution to someone else. Thanks for the research!