# Add widgets above a drawing area that fills its container

Tags: c, gtk3, glade, drawingarea

#### Hello,

I would like to know if it is possible with GTK3/Glade to install a drawing area in the background and put widgets on top of it (GtkPalette for example). I'd also like to integrate a zoom to enlarge the drawing area when there's no more room or conversely to shrink it with a zoom. I've only been doing my research for two days but it's not very conclusive. I also did several tests on Glade.
I first tried to put my drawing area and widgets in a GtkFixed. But the drawing area does not automatically fill the GtkFixed. Also, I have no proof that it doesn't fit over the widgets. Indeed, I have the impression that it is not designed for that. Also, via the code I haven't been able to fill the GtkFixed with the Drawing Area yet. 
The other method that I tried, is to use a GtkBox and put my drawing area directly in it. However, this completely prevents me from putting widgets in it. I come here to ask you the question because I'm still a beginner and I'd like to avoid wasting even more time on something that may be difficult to do.
Concerning the zoom, I have little hope but it's not essential for the moment. I'm attaching the type of application I'm trying to make and my current application so that you can better visualize what I'd like to do in relation to the drawing area.
Thank you in advance for your answers.
This is a good example of what I'm looking for (at the end): https://circuitverse.org/simulator
This is a screenshot of my application: https://ibb.co/rwQkGGM

Comment: Create a `vbox` for the outer container that is placed in the window. The use `gtk_box_pack_start` to add your palette and again to add your drawing area below it. See [GtkBox](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBox.html). That is the correct way to go.

Comment: ok thank you, I will try it and I will give a feedback.

Comment: Take a look at [GtkLayout](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkLayout.html)

Comment: That's an option, but only if you need to place child-widgets inside your drawing area. Unless that is an absolute requirement -- you are better off keeping your buttons/widgets/etc.. separate from the drawing area. Completely depends on what you need to do...

Comment: Finally, the Vbox doesn't work for my idea because it creates a new box to store each new item instead of putting the last added widget in the foreground. On the other hand, while testing with `vbox` and `gtk_box_pack_start`, I came across GtkOverlay out of curiosity and it seems to be what I'm looking for. It doesn't separate the widgets with each addition and overlay them. I came across this, which helped me a lot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296618/how-can-i-render-text-with-transparent-background-over-other-widgets-in-gtk.

Comment: However, I still have a more stylistic problem (I haven't done much research on it yet). I'd like to create a folder to save my widgets and be able to call them easily in the code (for example the palettes or the many icons, external images I use). Currently, I have to put my images in the hierarchy directly and it's not very nice. Same for the palettes. They're much easier to do directly on glade, that's why I'd like to put them somewhere so I can get them back. As I said I haven't done enough research yet but if anyone comes by with an interesting idea, I'll take it.

Comment: Actually, this is not an obligation at all. It's mostly in relation to the idea I had in mind. But if it doesn't correspond to my expectations I would end up opting for this option (especially as it doesn't change much in the end). However, I think I'll go and watch GtkLayout. It seems more suitable than GtkOverlay for my needs. Thank you for your valuable comments lb90 and David C. Rankin.

Comment: Hi William, could you provide an image that shows clearly what you are trying to replicate?

Comment: I would like to put several GtkPalette that I have customized with my own icons above each drawing area. That's why I'd like to just get them already made in Glade and put them above the drawing area like on this prototype we made for our project (I'm a french student). That's why I'm asking if there's a way to store widgets that can be retrieved from the code at any time. [my_prototype](https://ibb.co/X4J9hxk)